# Space Complexity of Two Versions of Merge Sort

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort, space-complexity

Suppose we have two different versions of merge sort below. For general purposes, the merge function will combine the inputted lists and return an entirely new list.

```
def merge_sort(items):
  if len(items) <= 1:
    return items

  middle_index = len(items) // 2
  left_split = items[:middle_index]
  right_split = items[middle_index:]

  left_sorted = merge_sort(left_split)
  right_sorted = merge_sort(right_split)

  return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)
```

```
def merge_sort(items):
  if len(items) <= 1:
    return items

  middle_index = len(items) // 2

  left_sorted = merge_sort(items[:middle_index])
  right_sorted = merge_sort(items[middle_index:])

  return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)
```

My question is: would the space complexity of these two functions vary?

(NOTE: When I refer to space complexity, I mean auxillary space complexity)

I learned how to compute the space complexity of recursive functions in a rudimentary light. Put simply, we are looking for the maximum space that our recursion will take during its execution. This is most often achieved when we recurse all the way down to our base case, meaning that the call stack contains the maximum number of frames––each containing a particular amount of data. This can be summarized with the following equation:

```
$$S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^maximum recursion depth k$$
(where k represents the amount of space occupied by a single function in terms of i (level))
```

Considering the first function, we are creating two lists of 1/2n length (along with constant trivial space for other computations which will we disregard to be concise) before the first recursive call. Thus, the first function call *initially* takes n total space before the first recursive call, where n is the original input. On the next recursive call, we are dealing with a list the size of 1/2n. Again, before the subsequent recursive call, we create two lists of 1/4n length (1/2n space in total). So, since the maximum recursion depth of merge sort is log<sub>2</sub>n, we can create a general summation for the total space occupied at the base case:

```
$$S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^((log_2 n) - 1)(0.5)^i + 0$$
```

NOTE: We only sum up to the second to last level because the final level (the base case) will not create a new list; thus, the space complexity of the final recursive call is just constant space, which is trivial in this example. Of course, if I were to be more mathematically rigorous, then each level (including the final level) would consume a constant number of space in addition to the space consumed by its respective list creation. In the lens of big O notation, however, this term of constant space would be rendered insignificant. So, for the sake of concision, I will ignore it and add a "0" term to represent the base case level.

Considering the second function, we are creating a single list of 1/2n length (along with constant trivial space for other computations which will we disregard to be concise) before the first recursive call. Thus, the first function before the first recursive call call *initially* takes 1/2n total space, where n is the original input. On the next recursive call, we are dealing with a list the size of 1/2n. Again, before the subseqeunt recursive call, we create a single list of 1/4n length (1/4n space in total). So, since the maximum recursion depth of merge sort is `log<sub>2</sub>n`, we can create a general summation for the total space occupied at the base case:

```
$$S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^((log_2 n) - 1) 1/2n(0.5)^i + 0$$
```

NOTE: We only sum up to the second to last level because the final level (the base case) will not create a new list; thus, the space complexity of the final recursive call is just constant space, which is trivial in this example. Of course, if I were to be more mathematically rigorous, then each level (including the final level) would consume a constant number of space in addition to the space consumed by its respective list creation. In the lens of big O notation, however, this term of constant space would ultimately be rendered insignificant. So, for the sake of concision, I will ignore it and add a "0" term to represent the base case level.

While I understand that both of these summations will simplify to the same big O notation of `O(n)`, I am curious if my understanding is correct. Since the second function waits to create the second list until after the first recursive call, the function call as a whole actually occupies less space when we eventually reach the base case. On the contrary, the first function creates both lists before the first recursive call, meaning that we leverage double the space on each recursive call down to the base case. So, at any given time, the first function will occupy double the space. In this case, however, the difference in space appears to be trivial.

In this a proper interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

There's no significant difference. Both *use* O(n) additional space. The first one just frees it (or can free it) immediately after the recursive call returns, instead of waiting until your local variables `left_split` and `right_split` go out of scope at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions of the merge sort algorithms are quite similar and follow the same divide-and-conquer approach. They both use recursion to split the input list into smaller sublists until each sublist has only one element, and then merge the sorted sublists together.
**Version 1** directly slices the list inside the merge_sort function, while Version 2 splits the list before calling the merge_sort function. Both versions achieve the same goal of sorting the input list using merge sort, but Version 2 might have a slight advantage in terms of memory usage and performance.